# Building EFI applications with UDK14/15 targeted to AARCH64 using Visual Studio 2012/2015//WinDDK 8.1 ARM Compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2012, arm, arm64, uefi, wdk

Is it possible to build EFI applications with UDK14/UDK15 targeted to AARCH64 using Visual 2012/2015/WinDDK8.1 ARM Compiler in windows platform?

I have tried building the UDK 14/15 code using VS2012 ARM Compiler and I am receiving __rd_udiv,__rt_udiv64 kind of linker errors in the UDK code.These errors I am not facing with other compilers such as GCC for ARM or x64 VS12/15 compiler.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Visual Studio is that MSFT has not yet released an aarch64 (MSFT calls this ARM64) compiler as of VS2015.